# Magento 1.9 - Cannot create and save email template

Tags: magento, email, templates

I have tirelessly tried to create and save an email template to no avail. I have tried different locales and all the templates load fine. But whenever I try to save the template I get this error message - "The template Name must not be empty." although the template name field is filled. What could be the problem?

Answer (score 0):

I strongly recommend the Yireo Email Override extenson (see https://www.yireo.com/software/magento-extensions/email-override). One advantage is templates are stored as files and so can be managed through source control (such as git).

Comment: I installed the Yireo extension way before I posted the question on the forum but it still didn't work.

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is mod_security. A fast way to see if that is the problem disable mod_security and try again (http://www.inmotionhosting.com/support/website/modsecurity/disable-mod-security-via-modsec-manager).

Remember to enable again mod_security then find which rule make you problems
http://www.inmotionhosting.com/support/website/modsecurity/find-and-disable-specific-modsecurity-rules
and then make changes to your files (file permission etc.) or you can disable that rules (not recommended).

Comment: You should add essential parts of the link resources as part of your answer.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue and addressed it as follows. I deleted most of the content I wanted to have in the email leaving behind just our logo (I suspected the system was rejecting something in the content). I saved the template without most of the content. It saved properly. I then opened up the template and pasted in the rest of my html and saved it.